# Canvas underlying bitmap

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

How many underlying bitmaps has Canvas element. I think it must have at least two, one for buffer, one for screen projection. Is it browser specific or is it standarized (if yes, then where) count?

Comment: I think it depends on the context applied to the `<canvas>` element. You may find some clues [around here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-canvas-element:the-canvas-element-23)

Comment: This is implementation detail of a web browser.

If you ask the question "how many underlying bitmaps `<canvas>` has in a web browser X when I do Y you can get an accurate answer.

Comment: But it's still a good question :)

Comment: in 4.12.4.2.1 of the link provided by @Kaiido you can see that up to 4 buffers might be required, but 1 or 2 can do the trick. Note that this is a 'non-normative' section, meaning every browser is free to implement this in any way. I can only say Chrome / Desktop is double-buffered. I'd bet all decent browsers did choose also double buffering.

Comment: I can agree with you @Kaiido. My private investigation detect that 100 layers of 1280 x 800 allocates ~700-800 MB what shows that in fact there is 2x100 buffers.
=(1280*800*4)/1024/1024*100 = 390MB for one buffer. Ofc it's for chrome

Answer (score 0):

*"How many bitmaps make up the Canvas element?"*

**Zero!**

The canvas element maintains an array containing the red, green, blue & alpha values of each pixel it will display on the screen. In modern browsers that array is typed `Uint8ClampedArray`. You can think of this array as a kind of bitmap--but it is not.

*So the closest answer to your question:* Canvas has one or more RGBA pixel arrays that acts as a "backing store" or "buffer".

When the browser requests the canvas to redraw, this array (or an alpha pre-multiplied version of it) is blitted to the GPU (or if no GPU exists, to the CPU).

You can fetch this RGBA array using:

```
// Fetch the imageData object that contains the pixel array
var imgData = context.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

// Fetch the pixel array itself
var pixelArray = imgData.data;
```

Then you can manipulate each pixels RGBA values and push your manipulated array back to the canvas using `context.putImageData(pixelArray,0,0)`. Executing putImageData will automatically cause the browser to blit the modified array onto the display during the browsers next screen refresh.

You can refer to the "WhatWG" for official standards & specifications relating to the canvas element: https://developers.whatwg.org/the-canvas-element.html#the-canvas-element.

However, each browser may implement the standards & specifications as they see fit and some browsers take longer to implement the standards and specifications. Some browsers are now open-source so you can look at each browser's implementing code, if needed.

Comment: Then what about [this](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#implementation-notes) and 5.4 , 5.5 and 5.7 of [this link](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/1.0/#5.4). Ok it's about the context applied onto the canvas element but so are, `getImagedata` and `putImageData` methods which are specific to the CanvasRenderingContext2D context.

Comment: @Kaiido Indeed, the best metaphor for the way canvas stores its pixel data is the Bitmap. But canvas does not actually format its backing stores as bitmaps. There are no bitmap headers, no masks, no color table, no profile, etc.  Canvas does store its pixel data similarly to bitmap’s pixel (sequential R,G,B,A or A,R,G,B) . Last time I looked, Foxfire alpha multiplies its  pixel data for efficiency. I forget if Chrome pre-multiplies or not. I can’t speak to WebGL…I just haven’t looked into its internals. Cheers!